# Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' (111)

Tags: php, mysql

*Before reading this know that I am new to this kind of stuff and have been searching for hours for an answer but keep running into issues.*

I've just set up a DigitalOcean droplet installed LAMP and have uploaded my site via FileZilla. The only issue is whenever I load up my site by going to the ip or the domain I get this error:

```
Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' (111).
```

I have tried making bind-address = 0.0.0.0 however that did not seem to work either.When I restart MYSQL I find that bind-address is indeed set to 0.0.0.0 and yet I am still having this issue.

When checking `netstat -nat |grep :3306`

It returns

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Looks like it's only accepting localhost connections?
If anyone knows the solution to this problem it would be a great help, and again I have been scouring the internet for about 3 hours now looking for solutions and just creating more errors.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried to check your services ?they are enable or disabled?

Comment: Not sure how to check if they are already on, but when I try mysql start I get the error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I have looked this up as well and cannot find a way to fix this.